# what EXACTLY is the difference between const thisFunction = () => {} and const thisFunction = ({}) => {}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Check this function below, what would I call the thread thats coming in on this function below, is it a parameter? or is it a destructured part of an object? does the curly brace mean this is still a parameter? im just a little confused

```
const ChatThread = ({thread}) => {

return (
<div>
</div>
)
}
```

if I do the same function like below i get an error with the thread, why is it required to use the curly braces to get the data?

```
const ChatThread = (thread) => {

return (
<div>
</div>
)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? In the code you posted, there should be no difference because the function does not use the parameter anyway.

Comment: I just want to know syntax, is it still technically called a parameter if it has curly braces?

Comment: That does answer my question!

Comment: (thread) => is a parameter(object) passed to this function. ({thread}) this is like extracting the property thread from passed parameter. In short this is like param.thread. so it's destructuring

Comment: Short answer: `({thread})` expects an object (note the curly braces) containing the property `thread`, whereas `(thread)` expects any parameter